# Should I encrypt hidden field time when using for validation(spam prevention)?

Tags: php, forms, validation, datetime

I have a from which get a little bit of spam and don't want to apply a captcha so was looking at using a datetime field within the form and then compare the time the form was created to the time it was submitted.

So I was thinking of using the below to generate the time

```
$date = $today = date("H:i:s");
```

And then within the hidden input field the below

```
echo $date;
```

Is it necessary to encrypt time? (especilly in the circumstances of preventing spam etc)

Also in my POST validation when comparing the times would I just create a new time and then coampare that to the $_POST['hiddenfieldname']?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is not needed. Having input field as a spam prevention feature is already enough as spam bots are rarely manipulating with DOM and even if they would have to know the mechanism behind the form.

Yet if you take under consideration that some users may be fooling around, then encrypting your value would be a good idea, as well as giving it uncommon id tag name.